# Unable to relocate to new SVN repository

Tags: svn, url, repository

I'm trying to run the command:

```
svn switch --relocate https://<old url> https://<new url>
```

But it's returning:

```
svn: '.' is not a working copy
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

1. `--relocate` option is deprecated since 1.7, current Subversion is 1.8.1, `svn relocate` recommended now
2. relocate uses THREE parameters:

`switch --relocate FROM-PREFIX TO-PREFIX [PATH...]`

and if last parameter (path to Working Copy) is skipped, `.` assumed. Because relocation non-working copy haven't sense, you **must** to define correct location of Working Copy (result of `svn checkout`) in any possible form

Answer (score 0):

"working copy" means the current directory has a sub folder with name ".svn".

Make sure whether your current directory is under the control of SVN.